# Creating WebForms App in MVC 3 + Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a small application developed in ASP.NET 2.0 WebForms. For learning purpose, I am thinking to convert this application to MVC 3 + Entity Framework. Below is the simplest example to simulate my application. Nothing fancy.

**Application Layout:**

(image should read "input fields" and not "files")

[image]

**Architecture:**

[image]

**Key points:**

1. Methods in Service layer is using ADO.NET `SqlCommand` `ExecuteReader` method to execute stored procedures
2. Most of the manipulation etc. logic is done in stored procedures. Hardly any manipulation of data in Service layer

Now I want to convert this application to MVC.

**Questions:**

1. What benefit do I get (technically) if I convert this application into MVC + Entity Framework?
2. How do I go about it?
3. I have looked at some basic MVC3 tutorials but they all talk about EF code-first, which I don't think will fit in my case since I want to use the existing stored procedures. Is that correct?

**Note:** I want to use the existing stored procedures. Say I don't have control on DB structure changes.

**Update 1:**

1. There isn't a single inline query in my application. Even the smallest little query is a stored procedure. Tons of them.
2. Using SQL Server and almost nil chances of changing to any other DBS.

**Update 2:**

My webforms application is 99% complete and can go live anytime but due to some business hurdles it hasn't. In mean while I thought if I can convert (i.e. develop) this to MVC, I will learn plus if it works out can go live (my first MVC) instead of the webforms one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering the specific questions I'll point out that you should probably seperate the choices into 2:

1. Converting the presentation layer to use MVC instead of WebForms.
2. Converting the data layer to use EF instead of ADO.NET.

Now for your questions

1. Benefits of MVC include better control over HTML, better testability, etc. Benefits of EF include abstracting away DB-specific things (you could theoretically replace SQL Server with MySQL, assuming an appropriate MySQL provider), LINQ support, etc. Of course there are also costs to such a transition.
2. Divide and conquer. As stated earlier you don't have to do everything at once. Start with the presentation layer and convert it to MVC. Remember that you can have mixed WebForms and MVC applications so you don't have to transition all your pages at the same time. Then convert your data layer to EF. Or start in the reverse order, whatever makes sense for your project.
3. [Not an expert in this topic] if you rely heavily on SPs than consider traditional EF. If you have only a few SPs then you could consider code first + handling the SPs with DataSets (potentially wrapped in custom built classes) to make everything work, though that might get complicated. As before, you don't have to move to EF if the cost is too high.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post a bit to include more info. So what I understand is from the coding standpoint or performance wise, my application won't see much of a difference. What interests me is cleaner markup and using Razor syntax. Also I use updatePanels and was thinking getting out of the code-behind thing and start using jquery+ajax and that's when RazorViews seems promising.

Answer (score 2):

What benefits do you get? It is completely wrong question. You should ask what problems do I have with current solution and how will these problems be solved by replacing data access with EF or replacing presentation layer with ASP.NET MVC?

As I understand you want to do this just for learning purpose - it has no business drive. In such case there are some points which will get you some ideas:

- If you don't want to replace existing SP logic with the common EF way you will get almost none benefits and you will not learn EF. EF allows using stored procedures either for retrieving mapped entities or for loading custom classes. Mapped entities usually represent either views or tables from the database - it is not clear here if you even want to define any mapped entities. The only benefit you get when loading custom classes is automatic populating of properties from the result set. It means that you will need class for each SP result which will have properties named exactly the same as columns in result sets. SPs in EF doesn't support multiple result sets (by default) and also doesn't support automatic loading of relations.
- When moving from ASP.NET Web Forms to ASP.NET MVC + Razor you can be almost sure that non of your front end code will be usable in the new solution. You will simply create new project and do you front end from scratch.
- As described by @marcind these two changes are completely independent - you can do one without other.

Comment: You made a nice point about mapping entities to SPs. I figured that I will have to follow Schema First approach with EF since I already have existing DB. With that approach I might not have to explicitly create my Person(Entity) class but I can rely on VS to do that. I will need to check more on the multiple resultset(few of my SPs does that). With Razor, my major concern is I have UserControls that interact with each other. I know with Razor, I can have partialView but I don't know how they will interact with each other though. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I recommend asking separate question about replacing UserControls.

Comment: If you want to check some possibility with returning multiple result sets check EFExtensions http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions